# time complexity and theta algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, big-o

```
x=x+1 ; // constant time
// executes n times
for (i≡ 1 ; i<≡ n; i++
   m=m+2 // constant time
//outer loop executes n times
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   // inner loop executed n times
   for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
         k=k+1; // constant time
}
```

What is the time complexity function this code and what is the theta  Θ- algorithm?
(sorry for my english)

Comment: big O time complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly based on your analysis, the time complexity is:

```
(1 +‌ n + n^2) in \Theta(n^2) and O(n^2)
```

`n^2` is for the nested loops.